# ionic - cordova plugins gradle conflicts

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, android-gradle-plugin

This is ionic v1.

Hi, I'm using Firebase Plugin for notifications https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm and need to track geolocation when app is in background, so I also use (or trying to) this plugin: https://github.com/transistorsoft/cordova-background-geolocation-lt/

Problem comes when trying to build.

`ionic cordova build android`

```
    Found com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+, but version 9.0.0 is needed for the google-services
    plugin.
    Found com.google.firebase:firebase-core:+, but version 9.0.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.
    Found com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:+, but version 9.0.0 is needed for the google-services plugin.
    :processDebugGoogleServices FAILED

    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.
    > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information
    about the latest version is available at
    https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of
    com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.

    * Try:
    Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

    BUILD FAILED

    Total time: 1.56 secs
    Error: /Users/id/Documents/a/b/c/project/platforms/android/gradlew: Command
    failed with exit code 1 Error output:
    FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

    * What went wrong:
    Execution failed for task ':processDebugGoogleServices'.
    > Please fix the version conflict either by updating the version of the google-services plugin (information
    about the latest version is available at
    https://bintray.com/android/android-tools/com.google.gms.google-services/) or updating the version of
    com.google.android.gms to 9.0.0.
```

I've trying to fix this by switching numbers, reading documentation about gradle configs but I cannot seem to find the solution. (I think switching versions is the solution..)

These are .gradle files of plugins.

**cordova-background-geolocation-lt.gradle**

```
repositories{    
  jcenter()
  flatDir{
      dirs 'src/android/libs'
   }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:+'
    compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
    compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'
    compile(name:'tslocationmanager', ext:'aar')
    // logback-android
    compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.21'
    compile 'com.github.tony19:logback-android-core:1.1.1-6'
    compile('com.github.tony19:logback-android-classic:1.1.1-6') {
        exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'android'
    }
}
```

**cordova-plugin-fcm.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
            jcenter()
            mavenLocal()
        }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    }
}
// apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// class must be used instead of id(string) to be able to apply plugin from non-root gradle file
apply plugin: com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin
```

Btw, i'm using platform `android@6.2.3` from cordova. If there's anything else you need or want to know, please ask.

Thanks in advance for your time!

Comment: Are you building locally on your machine or in the cloud?

Comment: On my machine, iMac.